# SharePoint 2013 not sending to OpenSearch endpoint the right {searchTerms}

Tags: sharepoint-2013, opensearch

I made an OpenSearch endpoint on my website, which allow SharePoint (2013) to make requests and get results from my database.

I created a custom Search Origin in SharePoint (2013) like so:
[image]

After setting this source as the default one, I tried a simple search: "test"

But the request parameter received seems to be altered as all I get in the q parameter is `((test AND) AND)`.

**My question is**: Why, even if I haven't configure any request transformation, am I not getting exactly what I've typed in?

I tried using {searchBoxQuery} but then I don't get anything. I've looked over forums but everyone wants to do transformation, which I'm not.

Comment: Not an expert. Does this link help? https://technet.microsoft.com/library/jj219620(v=office.15) Found on: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/fa7db7b8-d3c0-4ceb-8bcc-79ce54a20af4/sending-search-box-query-text-as-is-to-opensearch-result-source?forum=sharepointsearch

Comment: @Elfayer Yes I've looked at it. And it states that if you don't want transformations, just leaves {searchTerms} (default configuration). This is exactly why this question is for, why am I getting transform requests without transformations configured